# How to remove unused CSS rules during Meteor build?

Tags: css, meteor, uncss

Is there a package that will automatically clean the css rules in my meteor app? I heard about purifyCSS and UnCSS as well as several Chrome extentions to help with this (for example "CSS remove and combine") and was wondering if it can be done directly in Meteor

Comment: Might want to check this out - https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-remove-unused-css-rules-during-meteor-build/17405

Comment: I did, the last comment from 7h ago is mine :)

Answer (score -1):

Maintaining your code is a mandatory task in order to keep your projects in tact.

However, since you are in this position a relatively easy way to gain some speed and a cleaner output is [this library](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss).

Comment: Okay, how do I use it with a meteor app?